# In web application, format date to locale on Chrome not working

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, localization, internationalization, locale

I have my application, which localized dates and numbers.

```
new Date().toLocaleDateString('de-CH');
new Intl.NumberFormat('de-CH', { style: 'currency', currency: 'USD' }).format(10000000.11);
```

The numbers are localized fine (they really do format some specific de-CH stuff correctly) but the dates are shown in US like format as `mm/dd/yyyy`.

When I open empty new tab (which I think is `chrome-search://local-ntp/local-ntp.html` url) also the date formatting works correctly.

---

My setup: Chrome v78, Ubuntu 19.10.

Is working fine on some other setups like: Firefox on the same laptop, Chrome v77 Ubuntu 18.04, and MacOS Chrome

---

EDIT: I added locales to Ubuntu after noticing the issue as per https://askubuntu.com/a/76106/754424. Perhaps Chrome didn't catch them correctly. I reinstalled Chome now, but same outcome.

Comment: Chrome 78 on Windows correctly gives `19.11.2019`. Let me check in ubuntu.

Comment: Chromium `Version 78.0.3904.97 (Official Build) Built on Ubuntu , running on Ubuntu 19.04 (64-bit)` also correctly gives `19.11.2019`

Comment: Which page have you tested, how you tested that? When on `google.com` in devtools console I type `new Date().toLocaleDateString('de-CH');` and it gives me `mm/dd/yyyy` which is incorrect.

Comment: I'm using this: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/x542r8ce/ I'm installing Google Chrome now, will report back

Comment: Let me say I added that locale to my Ubuntu (minimal installation) later with https://askubuntu.com/a/76106/754424. Perhaps Chrome did not catch the updates correctly. I might try to reinstall Chrome.

Comment: Ok, I'm using a clean install and again it works fine: https://i.imgur.com/rEOSQac.png

Comment: I installed Chromium 78 on the same laptop with Chrome 78 issue, and it works fine. Maybe the re-installation of Chrome didnt clean its stored settings and bindings.

Comment: So a reinstall of Chrome didn't fix this?

Comment: This is correct. But it kinda loaded all my data immediately. Like the uninstall didnt happen at all. Perhaps I had to restart the PC in between.

Comment: @ChrisG check my answer, I solved the issue

Answer (score 0):

I now did a **complete** uninstall of Chrome (uninstall in Ubuntu Software and all chrome mentions in my home folder `~`). After fresh install the issue is solved and `de-CH` date formatting works correctly.

So it seems Chrome and OS didn't bind properly on locale install after Chrome was installed.

---

My related bug in Chromium: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1026229&q=format%20date%20component%3ABlink&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified