# Javascript dates do not display properly in Arabic locales

Tags: javascript, date

```
new Date().toLocaleDateString(
          "en-US",
          {
            day: '2-digit',
            month: '2-digit',
            year: 'numeric',
          })
```

```js
console.log(
  new Date().toLocaleDateString(
    "en-US",
    {
      day: '2-digit',
      month: '2-digit',
      year: 'numeric',
    })
);
```

gives me "08/19/2021".

Whereas

```
new Date().toLocaleDateString(
          "ar-XB",
          {
            day: '2-digit',
            month: '2-digit',
            year: 'numeric',
          })
```

```js
console.log(
  new Date().toLocaleDateString(
    "ar-XB",
    {
      day: '2-digit',
      month: '2-digit',
      year: 'numeric',
    })
);
```

is giving me "19‏/08‏/2021"

```
new Intl.DateTimeFormat("ar-XB", {
            day: '2-digit',
            month: '2-digit',
            year: 'numeric',
          }).format(new Date());
```

```js
console.log(
  new Intl.DateTimeFormat("ar-XB", {
    day: '2-digit',
    month: '2-digit',
    year: 'numeric',
  }).format(new Date())
);
```

also gives me "19‏/08‏/2021"

How can I get the correct date format?

Comment: In what context are you using this? The last two return arabic which is right to left

Comment: in Chrome and Brave browser console

Comment: added snippets for each. It looks like it's just console output anomalies. Node does fine (in VSCode terminal) and Safari logs '08/19/2021'

Comment: Thank you @pilchard. I am using this in a React app, and it shows up as "19‏/08‏/2021" in the UI. Running the app in Safari gives the correct format. Chrome and Brave have this issue.

Comment: There's an old bug addressing this: [Issue 1026229](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1026229&q=format%20date%20component%3ABlink&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified) and some related questions: [In web application, format date to locale on Chrome not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58932534/in-web-application-format-date-to-locale-on-chrome-not-working), [How does toLocaleDateString() work in Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14835858/how-does-tolocaledatestring-work-in-chrome)

Comment: What is the locale `ar-XB`? Which country/Language is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using *formatToParts* to get the parts and format them manually. They still appear as English characters in Chrome, but at least the format is what you expect.

```js
let {year, month, day} = new Intl.DateTimeFormat("ar", {
            day: '2-digit',
            month: '2-digit',
            year: 'numeric',
          }).formatToParts(new Date()).reduce((acc, part) => {
            acc[part.type] = part.value;
            return acc;
          }, {});

console.log(`${year}/${month}/${day}`);
```

PS
Using `${year.toLocaleString('ar')}` didn't help in Chrome, the characters are still English, not Arabic.